# How to make a hat larger in winter bash?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

In previous years it was possible to resize the hat easily. Now I don't know how to do it. The default size of the hat is too small, how do I make it bigger?

Answer (score 5):

In the Hat overview, click on *show controls*. Then pull the red indicator up:

> [image]

Comment: Thanks I completely missed it...

Comment: I kind of expected, from the user experience with other software, that the controls will appear somewhere while hovering the mouse over the object... or that the cursor will change from the moving arrow cross to the resizing arrows...